# Where does Folder Assistant stores Public Folder rules?

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook, exchange-2013, public-folders

O.K, i have to admit this is a demanding issue that probably goes deep down to the Exchange/AD structure; i'm just not sure where to look at for those info:

Before 2 weeks, i have successfully migrated an **Exchange 2010 server to Exchange 2013**. **Public Folders** have been also migrated together with their rules.

However there is an issue when trying to open the **Folder Assistant** tab on any of the **Public Folders** using any of the supported **Outlook** versions from any of the domain workstations. Did i say any **Public Folder**? That's not true as i am actually able to open the **Folder Assistant** option for just a few. After investigating i concluded that most likely the **Public Folders** on which the issue relies on, are those that had some rules in the past for some users that now maybe deleted or generally absent from the AD.

However in order to be able to resolve the issue, i need to be able to somehow see those rules for each **Public Folder** that **Folder Assistant** is not available and despite my thorough investigation i still cannot find the location where those rules are saved.

If someone is aware of this location, i would appreciate to let me know.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As this issue needed urgent attention, finally i found the solution to it.

Actually it is a workaround, using MFCMAPI tool i was able to browse the corrupted public folders where i found a line with the description "CORRUPTED DATA" which when i deleted, i gained access to each public folder and i was finally able to see the rules.

I hope this will be informative for someone in the future.